# Conversion of minimization to maximization objective under Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

I want to understand how Schnass $^\dagger$ arrived at the maximising objective as described below (on page 5)

\begin{aligned} \displaystyle \min_{D,A} \Vert X-DA \Vert_F^2 &= \min_D \sum_n \min_{|I|\leq S} \Vert x_n -D_ID_I^{\dagger}x_n \Vert_2^2 \\ &= \Vert X \Vert_F -   \max_D \sum_n \max_{|I|\leq S} \Vert D_ID_I^{\dagger}x_n \Vert_2^2 \end{aligned}

where $\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse, $S$ denotes the cardinality of column vectors $a_n$ of matrix $A$.

---

<sup>$^\dagger$ K. Schnass, [On the Identifiability of Overcomplete Dictionaries via the Minimisation Principle Underlying K-SVD](https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/personal/schnass/papers/14_sc_ksvd_acha.pdf), *Applied and Computational Harmonic Analysis*, 37(3):464--491, 2014.</sup>

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes edits are fine. This equation comes from the following article (page 5) https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/personal/schnass/papers/14_sc_ksvd_acha.pdf

Comment: Do you agree with my latest edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, decompose

$$
\| x_n - A x_n \|_2^2 = \| x_n \|_2^2 + \| A x_n \|_2^2 - 2 \langle x_n, A x_n \rangle
$$

In your case, $A = D_I D_I^{\dagger}$. By the properties of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, we know that $D_I D_I^{\dagger} = D_I D_I^{\dagger} D_I D_I^{\dagger}$. Therefore,

$$
\| x_n - D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \|_2^2 = \| x_n \|_2^2 + \| D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \|_2^2 - 2 \langle x_n, D_I D_I^{\dagger} D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \rangle
= \| x_n \|_2^2 - \| D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \|_2^2.
$$

The rest follows from the fact that $\sum_{n} \|x_n \|_2^2 = \| X \|_F^2$ and the property $\min_{z} x - f(z) = x - \max_{z} f(z)$.

**Another proof of the first decomposition**: $D_I D_I^{\dagger}$ is a projection, so by the Pythagorean theorem you have

$$
\| x_n \|_2^2 = \| D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \|_2^2 + \| (I - D_I D_I^{\dagger}) x_n \|_2^2 \Rightarrow
\| x_n - D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \|_2^2 = \|x_n\|_2^2 - \|D_I D_I^{\dagger} x_n \|_2^2.
$$